# How to minimize the use of anti-aliased fonts across all my desktop environment and applications?

Tags: debian, xfce, fonts, desktop, desktop-environment

I have configured some applications (Emacs, xfce4-term) to use bitmapped fonts, and disabled hinting/anti-aliasing.

But there are still a lot of anti-aliased fonts in my GUI desktop (xfce4).

If I simply turn off anti-aliasing through settings, I see a lot of ugly-looking fonts.  Much of this text, however, could be rendered just as well using bitmapped fonts, for which anti-aliasing is not necessary.  (For example, the font used for Google results, or for any generic dialog, menu, etc.)

Therefore, instead of turning off all anti-aliasing, I would prefer to configure all these "default" faces to use bitmapped fonts.

*I'm looking for global settings that would achieve this goal without having to individually customize every application.*

FWIW, my distro is Debian, and my desktop environment is xfce4.

Answer (score 2):

```
Put this in your ~.fonts.conf, and set Arial in your XFCE control panel.


<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Arial</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Helvetica</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Helvetica Neue</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Courier</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Courier New</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Tahoma</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>



 <match target="font">
  <test compare="more" name="weight">
   <const>medium</const>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>



 <match target="font">
  <test compare="more_eq" name="size" qual="any">
   <double>14</double>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <!-- Firefox -->
 <match target="font">
  <test compare="more_eq" name="pixelsize" qual="any">
   <double>15</double>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="pattern">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Helvetica</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="same" mode="assign" name="family">
   <string>Arial</string>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <test compare="eq" name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Skype UI Symbol</string>
  </test>
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>

</fontconfig>
```

Comment: omg, you save my day! thx a lot!